# building catkin workspace raspberry pi 4

Tags: ros-kinetic, catkin-make, raspberrypi

[image]

I have been trying to install the ROS dependencies for Raspberry pi 4. I keep getting the same errors no matter what I do. I have followed the instructions that are on installing ROS Kinetic on the Raspberry Pi. http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi
It is step 3.3

I am in the ros_catkin_ws/src which is what the instructions are saying I should be in when running the catkin_make command. Does anyone understand what is going on? I followed the instructions from the wiki why is it saying the source space does not exist?

Comment: Please link the tutorial saying to run catkin_make in the scr folder.  Please also show your python path since it looks like you never completed the install and are now trying to catkin_make.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are telling you to check your Python Path. Have you done that?

There is no point cloning packages into your source folder if you can't make an empty work space. Fix that first.

You don't run catkin_make from the scr folder. Only ever run it from the _ws folder.

Be aware there may now be files in your src folder that shouldn't be there and may cause issues later. My suggestion is to delete the scr folder and put it back togther, but you may be able to just delete the improperly placed files and folders that may now appear there.